# « S’avérer, s’avérer être, se révéler, se révéler être, se trouver être »

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation, reformulation

Contexte

Ils se sont retournés contre leur camp, qui s’est avéré le camp des méchants/s’est avéré être le camp des méchants/ s’est révélé le camp des méchants/ s’est révélé être le camp des méchants/ s’est trouvé être le camp des méchants.

> Ils se sont retournés contre leur camp, qui **s’est avéré** le camp des méchants.

> Ils se sont retournés contre leur camp, qui **s’est avéré être** le camp des méchants.

> Ils se sont retournés contre leur camp, qui **s’est révélé** le camp des méchants.

> Ils se sont retournés contre leur camp, qui **s’est révélé être** le camp des méchants.

> Ils se sont retournés contre leur camp, qui **s’est trouvé être** le camp des méchants.

Je suis ouvert aux reformulations.
Ce qui m’intéresse ici avant tout est de savoir quelles sont les formulations qui sont correctes et ensuite connaître quelle est la plus élégante.

Merci

Comment: On se révèle = on révèle soi-même, c'est une *action qui vient de soi* : il se révèle aux autres quand il *fait* quelque chose ; sans action, ce sont les autres qui constatent son *état* d'où la nécessité d'utiliser le mot *être* [ = ce qui est] pour signifier que c'est *un regard extérieur qui révèle un état*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« Ils se sont retournés contre leur camp, qui ...

- <s>... s’est avéré le camp des méchants. »</s>
- ... s’est avéré être le camp des méchants. »
- <s>... s’est révélé le camp des méchants. »</s>
- ... s’est révélé être le camp des méchants. »
- ... s’est trouvé être le camp des méchants. »

De mon point de vue, « … révélé être … » serait mieux dans ce cas.

Il n'ont pas vraiment *trouvé*, et *avéré* fait plutôt vieillot.

Comment: Pas si vieillot que ça *avérer*, qui atteint son [pic de popularité vers 2004](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=av%C3%A9r%C3%A9+%2B+av%C3%A8re+%2B+av%C3%A9rer+%2B+av%C3%A8rera+%2B+av%C3%A8rent+%2B+av%C3%A9r%C3%A9e+%2B+av%C3%A9r%C3%A9s+%2B+av%C3%A9r%C3%A9es&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=0&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28av%C3%A9r%C3%A9%20%2B%20av%C3%A8re%20%2B%20av%C3%A9rer%20%2B%20av%C3%A8rera%20%2B%20av%C3%A8rent%20%2B%20av%C3%A9r%C3%A9e%20%2B%20av%C3%A9r%C3%A9s%20%2B%20av%C3%A9r%C3%A9es%29%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score -3):

Complément de réponse.

Pour corroborer l'impression de [user Alexis Wilke](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/48404/17649), qui dans sa réponse fait part de sa préférence pour « s'être avéré être », voici deux  ngrams qui montrent qu'actuellement « s'être avéré être » l'emporte sur la version sans « être » ; cependant il n'existe pas de différence très importante.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Personnellement, ce que je perçois comme une plus grande spécificité de « s'être avérer être » me fait donner la préférence à ce dernier, mais c'est un jugement sur la base de ma familiarité bien moins que parfaite avec le verbe « s'avérer ».

Comment: That's a gross misinterpretation of what NGrams reports.

Comment: @jlliagre Non, je ne crois pas.

Comment: La comparaison entre les deux formes n'a pas de sens. *S'est avéré(e) le/la* est toujours (ou quasiment toujours) suivi d'un attribut du sujet (*Ce col s'est avéré le plus difficile*, *Elle s'est avérée la plus convaincante*, etc.), ce que ne peut être *le camp des méchants*.

Comment: Les formes que trouve Google NGram sont essentiellement du type: *S'est avéré le meilleur*, *S'est avéré le moins cher* etc.

Comment: La phrase de l'OP a un « qui » et donc le verbe « être » est nécessaire. Les statistiques d'usage ne réponde pas toujours une grammaire correcte. Par contre, il semblerait que mon commentaire sur « avérer » est effectivement incorrect.